# cannot click position fixed button on attachment fixed background

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here is whats's happening: 
I have a menu button with position fixed value, and on my page I have a div with a background-attachment that is also fixed.

While I am scrolling down it all works fine until I try to click the button the moment it goes on the fixed background and it does not click

```css
.page {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 1900px;
}


/*backgroun image*/

.unscrollable {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.page div.content {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
  <div style="width:80%">
    <button style="position:fixed;cursor:pointer; top: 0">click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="page">
    <div class="unscrollable" style="min-height:105%;"></div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know how to make my button work again? thanks in advance.
Also if you know a way to stop the opacity from applying to the button!
**Edit:** Thank you to @Huangism for the help!

Comment: You will need to provide enough code to reproduce the issue. As far as I can tell, your background image setting should have nothing to do with the button. Maybe it's the div it is in

Comment: @Huangism I tried running the sample code I just sent and it is actually reproducing the issue for me

Comment: The above code only shows a button on a blank page. You would at least need to include the css from your eternal css file, no one has access to that

Comment: The css code you need to reproduce the error is right there, you just need to copy paste it, and maybe put `background-color:grey` instead of `background-image: url("images/shrine.png");` . Now if you look the button works fine at the start, but if you scroll to where the screen is grey it stops working.

Comment: I changed the code so it only shows the part when it is not working, and not both where it works and does not.

Comment: Your code produces nothing but an empty screen with a button on it. There is a run code snippet button, you click on it and that's all you see. I have tried it with a fixed height instead of 105%. All you need to do is give the button z-index: 1;

Comment: Yes, the snipplet does not show the problem for some reason so I removed it.

Comment: The point is to reproduce the issue here, removing it does not solve that problem. I will edit the question so it can be reproduced but I already gave you the solution in my previous comment

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not see the comment while writing my last comment, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the z-index of the button to a higher level, than it will work.